# Put contents of a file in a variable

Tags: file, puppet

I have put some values in a file. In the puppet manifests I want to get the value of these variables. Is there a specific directory to put my file? Also, what should be the format of the file?

Comment: Probably you are trying to do what hiera already does? See http://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/ for details.

Comment: I want the manifests to take the node name from files. How can this be done?

Comment: Also, the local scope variables should not be used in hiera. I want to define the local scope variables from the file.

Comment: Node name from files: That is essentially an ENC, see http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/external_nodes.html. - "the local scope variables should not be used in hiera", I'm not sure what you mean by that, but I believe you've got it wrong. Local variables can and should be populated from data stored in Hiera.

Answer (score 0):

If this file on puppet-server, you can write functions for module. For example:

```
modules/my_module/lib/puppet/parser/functions/get_var.rb:
$: << File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '.'))
module Puppet::Parser::Functions
   newfunction(:get_var,
   :type => :rvalue) do |args|
   file_name = args[0]

      f = File.open(file_name)
      s = f.readline()
      return s
   end
end
```

And use it in manifests: `$test = get_var('/etc/puppet/configs.txt')`. This function return first string from file, but you can change it for your needs.
For file on client, you can write facter.

Comment: If I have to store these values in a file for example text file or xml file then how can I extract it to the manifests?

Comment: it`s depends from format. you can parse any file with any format and return one value or hash of values. That require some ruby skills, but ruby is very simple language. More simple than english :)

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile (since at least Puppet 5.5) you can use [`file`](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/function.html#file) (and [`binary_file`](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/function.html#binary-file)).